# How can I do a Facebook Connect with meteor.js?

Tags: facebook, meteor

I always get the following error when I do a FacebookConnect:

```
W20140817-21:48:56.623(2)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined
W20140817-21:48:56.624(2)? (STDERR)     at app/server/oauth.js:2:36
W20140817-21:48:56.624(2)? (STDERR)     at app/server/oauth.js:11:3
W20140817-21:48:56.625(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/username/copro/chatapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:161:10
W20140817-21:48:56.625(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20140817-21:48:56.625(2)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/username/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20140817-21:48:56.625(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/username/copro/chatapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Can you provide your facebook connect logic or are you using the default one from accounts-facebook + accounts-ui ? Are you sure you double checked the application registration process within facebook developer console ?

Comment: Also, try adding the service configuration package (`meteor add service-configuration`) and take the time to read these recommendations on how to login with external services : http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_loginwithexternalservice